# HTMLPurifier consumes tons of memory when HTML.Allowed is used?

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I have the following string:

```
<p>
    This is a test
</p>
<p>
    More test text.
</p>
<p>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">google</a>
</p>
```

When I run that through HTMLPurifier using this code:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../libraries/htmlpurifier-4.6.0-lite/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php');
$config   = \HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'code,span,div,label,a,br,p,b,i,del,strike,u,img,video,audio,blockquote,mark,cite,small,ul,ol,li,hr,dl,dt,dd,sup,sub,big,pre,code,figure,figcaption,strong,em,table,tr,td,th,tbody,thead,tfoot,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6');
$purifier = new \HTMLPurifier($config);
$sanitized = !empty($_POST['text'])?$purifier->purify($_POST['text']):null;
```

I get the error:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 51746711 bytes)

Why is this happening?

EDIT:

Changing the config line to this:

```
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'code,span,div,label');
```

Results in this error:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 37415543 bytes)

Comment: What's with the backslashes before HTMLPurifier?

Comment: @craniumonempty look up namespaces http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Are you using more namespaces though? I don't think that's required at all times except to distinguish class names in individual namespaces. It doesn't seem necessary, but I may be missing something... I posted a comment in their forum as well: http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,7478 since I can't test anything right now.

Comment: @craniumonempty in this example the backslashes aren't necessary, but in my actual code I use namespaces.

Comment: Ah, ok. I was curious as to why they were there. Thank you.

Comment: I was able to test with the given code (with exception of some formatting, setting a form to use with post, and a slightly different location of the files, but nothing significant) with no problems except for it spitting out "Warning: Element 'label' is not supported..." when using the other config (since I suppose they don't support "label"). There may be a problem elsewhere in the code that is triggered by this. I'm unsure.

Comment: NOTE: if it's the "set" function causing problems and has conflicts, you can look at it in   [...]\htmlpurifier-4.6.0-lite\library\HTMLPurifier\Config.php line 296 to see where the issue lies. They have error handling, so check your logs also to see if anything was thrown, but didn't show up on screen.